# Regex substituindo o valor dos grupos nomeados

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Eu tenho um regex cuja intenção é obter chave e valor de uma lista:

```js
const declarador = "(?<var>[a-z]+)=(?<val>[a-z]+)";
const regex = new Regex(`${declarador}(?:,${declarador})*`);
```

Tentei executar, mas infelizmente fui calorosamente recebido por um erro `Duplicate capture group name`.

Beleza tentei somente isto:

```js
const regex = /(?<var>[a-z]+)=(?<val>[a-z]+)(?:,(?<var_x>[a-z]+)=(?<val_x>[a-z]+))*/;
```

Mas aí que tá o problema! Quando eu testo o regex:

```js
const teste = "cria=zero,doll=treze,adultero=dezoito";
let result = regex.exec(teste);
console.log(result.groups);
```

Acontece que `doll=treze` está sendo substituído por `adultero=dezoito`, o que é muito estranho visto que eu incluí `*` no final do regex que significa que o grupo pode ser sequenciado de 0 a Infinitas vezes.

---

**Como posso retornar todos os valores sequenciados de `result.groups` sem sobrescrever os nomes?**

Comment: Eu acho mais simples fazer split pela vírgula, e depois para cada par chave=valor, fazer split pelo `=` - ou seja, nem precisa de regex

Comment: Isso faz parte do exemplo, no meu caso real eu estou tokenizando o uso da chave `let` no typescript. Por esse motivo eu acredito que não posso dar split por virgula.

Comment: Se precisar do regex da chave `let` eu passo (mas é imensamente grande)

Comment: Dito isso, quando um grupo tem um quantificador (no seu caso, pode ocorrer zero ou mais vezes), ele assume o valor da última ocorrência, por isso não pega o `doll=treze`. Em algumas engines tem como pegar todos, mas no JavaScript não. Mais um motivo pra usar o split :-)

Comment: That's sad.. vou tentar aplicar essa expressão no meu código

Comment: "*eu estou tokenizando o uso da chave let no typescript*" - Não entendi, sugiro [edit] e colocar um [mcve] <- leia esse link, tem dicas pra melhorar o exemplo e deixar mais fiel ao seu cenário

Comment: vou checar... Mas vou testar seu código antes. Pode ser que funcione...

Comment: Se quiser mesmo continuar com essa regex, não precisa da complicação que foi sugerida abaixo, pode fazer apenas: https://ideone.com/6p2ySp - não ficou claro se o resultado tem que ser assim, então fiz outra alternativa também: https://ideone.com/L2E8F2 - de qualquer forma, veja que com split é mais simples, nem precisa dessa regex complicada, mas enfim...

Comment: Na verdade, eu consegui fazer o resultado desejado editando um pouco a sua resposta.  eu só tive que mudar algumas coisas do meu software. Mas obrigado!

Comment: Para os downvoters: Não adianta nada votar contra se não me explicarem o porquê. **Nunca poderei melhorar sem feedback!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar grupos sem captura para separar os pares chave-valor.

```
const declarador = "(?<var>[a-z]+)=(?<val>[a-z]+)";
const regex = new RegExp(`(?:${declarador},?)*`, 'g');

const teste = "cria=zero,doll=treze,adultero=dezoito";
let result = regex.exec(teste);

const resultObject = {};

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  let keyValue = result[i].split('=');
  resultObject[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
}

console.log(resultObject);

// Output: { cria: 'zero', doll: 'treze', adultero: 'dezoito' }
```